# How to insert objects with links and retrieve them

Tags: orientdb

I'm trying this with curl:

first insert a document:

```
curl --user admin:admin -X POST -d '{"@class":"Question"}' http://127.0.0.1:2480/document/home/
{"@type":"d","@rid":"#13:3","@version":6,"@class":"Question"}
```

second insert a document with a reference to the first one inside the items list

```
curl --user admin:admin -X POST -d '{"@class":"Question", "items":[{"@rid":"#13:3"}]}' http://127.0.0.1:2480/document/home/
{"@type":"d","@rid":"#13:2","@version":2,"@class":"Question","items":[{"@rid":"#13:3"}]}
```

finally I tried to get the last document:

```
curl --user admin:admin -X GET http://127.0.0.1:2480/document/home/13:2
{"@type":"d","@rid":"#13:2","@version":2,"@class":"Question","items":[{"@rid":"#13:3"}]}
```

But I need this:

```
{"@type":"d","@rid":"#13:2","@version":2,"@class":"Question","items":[{"@type":"d","@rid":"#13:3","@version":6,"@class":"Question"}]}
```

This is the documentation page:

https://github.com/orientechnologies/orientdb/wiki/OrientDB-REST

Edit:

I tried this and it did not work

```
curl --user admin:admin -X GET http://127.0.0.1:2480/document/home/13:2/*:-1
{"@type":"d","@rid":"#13:2","@version":2,"@class":"Question","items":[{"@rid":"#13:3"}]}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The second insert must contains the RID only:

```
{"@type":"d","@rid":"#13:2","@version":2,"@class":"Question","items":["#13:3"]}
```

To retrieve the full tree/graph set the fetch plan. Take a look at: https://github.com/orientechnologies/orientdb/wiki/OrientDB-REST#get---document

Use:

```
curl --user admin:admin -X GET http://127.0.0.1:2480/document/home/13:2/*:-1
```

Comment: I tried it, did not work. THX. I think the error is on the insertion of the second record.